# VB app to create multiple instances of Excel and run in background

Tags: vb.net, excel

I have a simple VB application which allows the user to select via a tick box a number of interfaces to generate.

I am looping through the ticked entries and for each, I am creating an instance of Excel and executing the appropriate Macro in the workbook.

I am looking to generate the Excel instance in the background for each ticked entry. Currently I have to wait for each Excel instance to run, before I can process the next.

Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Here's the Code Extract:

```
    MsgBox("Starting")

    parmExcelAppName = "..{Pathname}\Data Extract v1.4.xlsm"

    xlapp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

    xlbook = xlapp.Workbooks.Open(parmExcelAppName)
    xlapp.Application.Visible = True
    xlapp.Visible = False

    parmWorksheetName = "CURRENCY_RATE"
    parmWorksheetOutputSaveName = "C:\Users\pete05\Downloads\Interfaces"
    parmApplyFilter = "False"
    parmRunMode = "REFRESH"
    parmAddColumnHeadings = "True"
    parmEmailRecipients = "someone@companyname.com"

    xlapp.Application.Run("MOD00_RUNMODE.Run_BatchMode ", _
        "" & parmWorksheetName & "", _
        "" & parmWorksheetOutputSaveName & "", _
        "" & parmApplyJDAFilter & "", _
        "" & parmRunMode & "", _
        "" & parmAddColumnHeadings & "", _
        "" & parmEmailRecipients & "")

    xlapp.Quit()

    MsgBox("Finished")
```

Ideally the 'Starting' and 'Finished' messages would be displayed almost immediately and the Excel piece pushed into the background. I would then repeat for the next ticked entry.

Comment: It would help of you shared your code. It's certainly possible to create multiple instances of Excel. Sharing your code might give us a clue as to why you have to wait.

Comment: At the moment I only have a simple run script which displays a message when the process is initiated and stops when finished. Ideally I am expecting the process to be shunted into a separate instance and immediately display the 'Finished' message, which would then allow me to do the same for the next interface.

Comment: Looks like asynchronous calls in VBA are difficult. I can only suggest you convert the above code to a VBS that takes an appropriate parameter then use `Shell` to call it asynchronously from within VBA. Can you indicate what the parameter is that changes in this code? i.e. if you wanted to run two of these in parallel, would it be the .xls file that changes? I guess the `MOD00_RUNMODE.Run_BatchMode` macro is not something you have access  to?

Comment: I already have a VBS script which takes the parameters from individual interface short cuts to create the files. What I was after was a self contained EXE which would do the same but it sounds as all I will end up doing is call the VBS and feed it the same parameters. Out of interest how would I do this and run the VBS in the background? Thanks for the response.

Comment: Sorry for some reason I misunderstood I thought this code needed to be in Excel VBA. You should be able to call Excel asynchronously from a VB.Net app. I'll see if I can find some examples. Can you confirm you need to execute a macro in multiple _different_ Excel files simultaneously?

Comment: I must say that calling these asynchronously is likely to cause problems, i.e. if the excel macro fails you probably won't be able to get a message indicating so. You might get incorrect or incomplete data in the ouput and you wouldn't know... or the Excel file might get stuck open. A more robust solution is to try and grab the code in the `MOD00_RUNMODE.Run_BatchMode` macro and put it directly in your application, but I'm guessing you don't have access to it.

Comment: in fact, this makes me very nervous: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2800327/en-us

Comment: I currently have a single Excel workbook with multiple sheets, one for each interface. All the sheets call a common module to generate the data based on each sheet passing SQL to the common module to retrieve the appropriate information. As mentioned, my current solution has shortcut files to the VBS script and I am running all of these shortcuts concurrently. The Excel VBA script during runtime, export debug information to logfiles so if I do have any issues, I am capturing these. To date I have not had any issues but I understand your hesitation.

Comment: If the function of the excel sheet is to extract data with SQL and export it, I suggest removing Excel from the equation and doing it all in an EXE. This will allow you to at least perform queries asynchronously.

Answer (score 0):

I can only suggest at this stage that you try this. I don't know if it'll work. I suspect that even opening multiple files like this will open them in the same instance of Excel.

1. Create an excel file for each required input parameter
2. Add a startup macro to the excel file to call the macro above when the file opens
3. Open the excel file using a command line (i.e. `excel.exe "c:\book1.xlsx"`) using the `Shell` command.

This is just a stab in the dark really. Everything I've read indicates that this either won't work or won't work very well. To make this reliable you need to get the code from `MOD00_RUNMODE.Run_BatchMode`. If it's just calling a web service for example or reading from a database then you shoud be able to reproduce it outside of Excel and run it in parallel if the feeding system allows it.